# Не работает создание объекта из меню

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пробую создать объект из меню:

```
GameObject obj;
void CreateObject() {
    obj = new GameObject("TEST");
}
[MenuItem("Test/Create new object")]
private static void CreateObjectMenuItem() {
    CreateObject();
}
```

Однако получаю ошибку:
`error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Test.CreateObject()'`

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: В каком классе у Вас метод CreateObject()? В статичном? Если так, то `obj` и `CreateObject()` должны быть с модификатором `static`

Comment: Если класс не статичный, то ошибка в том, что нет экземпляров этого класса. Следовательно, класс нужно сделать статичным, и сделать статичными все его поля и методы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ООП что бы использовать метод какого-то класса, должен существовать какой-то инициализированный экземпляр этого класса или метод должен быть статичным и использовать статичные поля.

Что касается Unity, в момент использования созданного Вами пункта меню "Test/Create new object" не гарантируется наличие экземпляра Вашего класса. Поэтому (учитывая приведенный код) и сам класс, и все в нем методы и поля должны быть с модификатором `static`.

Не зная, что должно еще происходить с созданным объектом, могу предолжить такой код:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public static class TestUtils
{
  private static GameObject obj;

  private static void CreateObject()
  {
    obj = new GameObject("TEST");
  }

  [MenuItem("Test/Create new object")]
  private static void CreateObjectMenuItem()
  {
    CreateObject();
  }
}
```

Это при условии, что нет необходимости неследования от `MonoBehaviour`

Comment: Хороший ответ, но не совсем полный, считаю, стоит добавить, **как** нужно реализовывать то, что спросил автор.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, у автора вопроса код вполне рабочий (за исключением `static`-модификатора), поэтому даже и не подумал, что есть необходимость включать в ответ код... Но Вы меня уговорили))))

Comment: Вот теперь только проблема в том, что это статичное поле с игровым объектом никто и нигде не сможет установить/инициализировать. Такие ссылки нужно подцеплять либо через `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath`, либо через какие-то конфиги, реализованные на базе SerializedObject, либо же искать эти объекты в иерархии сцены.

Comment: Да и неизвестно, нужна ли автору вопроса эта ссылка на создаваемый игровой объект?

Comment: Пардон, подумал, что автор копирует игровой объект, тогда да, мой комментарий вообще не в тему)

Comment: Благодарю, всё работает!